# keep object after find tracker in vuforia with unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

please help me i faced the problem
I write a application with unity3d and vuforia that play video after detect the tracker , i want to fix video after detection in the camera and stop tracking , i edit onTrackingFound and onTrackingLost methods in TrackableEventHandler.cs several time but i cannot solve it , please help me to find a solution . thank a lot my frinds. 
the onTrackingFound  method is :

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>();

    // Enable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    // Enable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");

    // Optionally play the video automatically when the target is found

    VideoPlaybackBehaviour video = GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlaybackBehaviour>();
    if (video != null && video.AutoPlay)
    {
        if (video.VideoPlayer.IsPlayableOnTexture())
        {
            VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState state = video.VideoPlayer.GetStatus();
            if (state == VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.PAUSED ||
                state == VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.READY ||
                state == VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.STOPPED)
            {
                // Pause other videos before playing this one
                PauseOtherVideos(video);

                // Play this video on texture where it left off
                video.VideoPlayer.Play(false, video.VideoPlayer.GetCurrentPosition());
            }
            else if (state == VideoPlayerHelper.MediaState.REACHED_END)
            {
                // Pause other videos before playing this one
                PauseOtherVideos(video);

                // Play this video from the beginning
                video.VideoPlayer.Play(false, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    mHasBeenFound = true;
    mLostTracking = false;
}
```

and the onTrackingLost method is :

```
private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>();

    /*
    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Disable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }
    */
    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");

    mLostTracking = false;
    mSecondsSinceLost = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Full-screen

If I understand correctly, after detecting a trackable you want the tracking and AR camera view to stop, and play a full-screen video instead? If so, the easiest would be to simply disable Vuforia when you detect your trackable, i.e. in `OnTrackingFound`. Then you also have a full-screen `Canvas` object that has a disabled `RawImage` (`GameObject > UI > Raw Image`) as a child.

- AR Camera
- ImageTarget
- Canvas

  - RawImage *(has movie material, and is disabled initially)*

The `RawImage` will have a material assigned, where the material's main albedo texture is a movie file (so a [Movie Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html)), say an Ogg Theora `.ogv` file, let's call it the movie material. Then when you detect your trackable, simply enable the `RawImage` and `Play()` the movie material. So something like:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;       // for RawImage

public RawImage rawImage;   // public, so remember to drag-assign in editor

private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;             // disable Vuforia
    rawImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);                   // enable the RawImage
    ((MovieTexture)rawImage.material.mainTexture).Play();  // play the movie
}
```

---

### In 3D space

If instead, you do not want to play a full-screen video, but play a video in the position where the trackable is located in 3D space as seen through the camera, you could simply create a `Plane` object (`GameObject > 3D Object > Plane`) as a child of your trackable, let's give it the name Movie. Have the plane face the AR camera, assign the movie material to it, then disable its mesh renderer in the editor:

- AR Camera
- ImageTarget

  - Movie (*has movie material, and has disabled Mesh Renderer initially)*

In your `OnTrackingFound` method, you could then enable its renderer, and given a reference to its material as a `MovieTexture`, simply do `Play()`. Something like this on the trackable's event handler:

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        component.enabled = true;
    MovieTexture mov = (MovieTexture)transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture;
    if (!mov.isPlaying)
        mov.Play();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, after posting I saw that your post is tagged with [tag:android]. Movie Textures aren't supported on Android. For full-screen playback on Android, you would use `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` instead. More info on the [Movie Texture documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html).